# Multisite move server giving redirect loop

Tags: multisite, redirect

I'm currently trying to move my site dreamdoors.co.uk to my new server.

Everything is 100% working and fine on the old server but when I move it to the new server I get "This webpage has a redirect loop Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

What it seems to be doing is going from www.dreamdoors.co.uk to dreamdoors.co.uk back to www.dreamdoors.co.uk. The current live site only redirects from dreamdoors.co.uk to www.dreamdoors.co.uk

Everything is the same from htaccess to mutlisite forwarding.

Is there anything I could be missing.

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Updated the question to try and explain what the issue is better

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file, and make sure the database does not have `www.` addresses. This may be a DNS or HTTP server issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server was on the newest Plesk verison which comes with nginx which I was unaware of and was causing the redirect loops.

Nginx by default redirects to the non www, after editing the config file for this to www the problem was quickly solved.